# Python make a circular list to get out of range index

Tags: python, list, class

I'm looking for ways to make a list into circular list so that I can call a number with index out of range.

For example, I currently have this class:

```
class myClass(list):
  definitely __init__(self, *x):
    super().__init__(x)
```

which works as:

```
>> myList = myClass(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
>> print(myList)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

and after creating a list, I want to:

```
>> myList[2]
3
>> myList[12]
3
>> myList[302]
3
>> myList[-1]
10
>> myList[-21]
10
...
```

At the moment, index [12], [302] and [-21] are not possible since it is out of range for a single list, so I want to make a circular list if the index is out of range which will then make them possible.

- myList[12] = 3 because the circular list would be [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, ...].
- The list will be only made up with 5 or 10 numbers.

Comment: So what is the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you insist on creating an entire class for this, subclass `UserList`, implement `__getitem__` and use the [modulo operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) (`%`) with the length of the list:

```
class myClass(UserList):
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return super().__getitem__(item % len(self))

myList = myClass([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
print(myList[12])
```

outputs

```
3
```

Depending on your usage, it's possible you'll need to implement several other `list` methods.

**CAVEAT:** Be careful to not loop over `myList`. That will create an infinite loop because `__getitem__` will always be able to provide an element from the list.

Comment: Just be careful not to: `list(myList)`

Comment: Quite interesting.

Comment: @IdRandom yes, add `def __init__(self, *args): super().__init__(args)` to `myClass`

Comment: @MarkMeyer That's very interesting. Apparently `list(...)` uses `__getitem__` but not in a way that causes infinite recursion. It just sits there :)

Comment: @DeepSpace I would expect to call `iter(myList)` which results in a never-ending iterator. You can verify this by defining `__iter__()` on the class. Returning `iter(self.data)` might be away to avoid the issue.

Comment: @MarkMeyer right! it probably relies on  `StopIteration`, but that custom `__getitem__` never let that happen. Even `for n in myList` causes an infinite loop. Oops! :)