# replacing an item in a circular list

Tags: python, circular-list

So the task i need to do is create a class that can replace items in a circular list.

For example, if

```
MyList = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

MyList[100] = 6
```

this would need to return

```
MyList = [6, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Any tips on how you would go about setting this up?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. We are not here to do your homework, so please show us what you have tried so we can help!

Comment: I think what you may be looking for is a "Circular Linked List"

Comment: Maybe you would like to see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61350386/python-make-a-circular-list-to-get-out-of-range-index

Answer (score 1):

Well, assuming the `100` is expected to be modified (modulo) based on the list size, you can just use something like:

```
def replaceModulo(the_list, the_index, the_value):
    the_list[the_index % len(the_list)] = the_value
```

But you would be better off having a properly encapsulated class for doing this so that your code that uses it has a very specific API, and you can just modify the underlying code at will if, for example, you find a better way.

The class would maintain the fixed size list, along with a head and tail/size, and provide the standard operations along with your `replace` that you would like:

```
que = createCircularQueue(sz)
que.push(item)
item = que.pop()
old_value = que.replace_at(idx, new_value)
```

That way, all the code for converting `idx` in to the *actual* index (it depends on head) will be hidden away.